# selecting top n rows in each group of dataframe spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a df in spark scala and i need to groupBy id and sort based on DateTime which is in the second column and take only top 5 rows of each group

```
------------------------------------
|id|             DateTime          |
------------------------------------
|340054675199675|15-01-2018 19:43:23|
|340054675199675|15-01-2018 10:56:43|
|340028465709212|10-01-2018 02:47:11|
|340054675199675|09-01-2018 10:59:10|
|340028465709212|02-01-2018 03:25:35|
|340054675199675|28-12-2017 05:48:04|
|340054675199675|21-12-2017 15:47:51|
|340028465709212|18-12-2017 10:33:04|
|340028465709212|16-12-2017 19:55:40|
|340028465709212|16-12-2017 19:55:40|
|340028465709212|12-12-2017 07:04:51|
|340054675199675|06-12-2017 08:52:38|
------------------------------------
```

```scala
    val dfTop = df.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where($"rn" === 10).drop("rn")

    val dfMax = df.groupBy($"id".as("grouped_id")).agg(first($"DateTime").as("max_value")).limit(10)

    val dfTopByJoin = df.join(broadcast(dfMax),
      ($"id" === $"grouped_id") && ($"DateTime" === $"max_value"))
```

Comment: Are you working with spark streaming [given the tag]?

Comment: Yeah I’ll be getting these data from streaming

Comment: Is it Dstreams or structured streaming?

Comment: Structured. But as of now I’m more interested to sort the above df.

Comment: Sorting works differently for based on how you are working with that DF, i.e. structured streaming or batch, so this information is necessary.

Comment: why you're putting rn ===10 in the first line ?
you can just filter lines where rn <= 5 to get the top 5 and that's it.
may be I miss something

Comment: Basically it compares with 10rows out of which it return only one row. But that’s not my expected stuff. Anyways thanks.

Comment: why don't you do the following:
    
val w=  Window.partitionBy("id")
    
val dfTop = df.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where($"rn" <= 5 ).drop("rn")

Comment: Thanks a ton! 
`val dfTop = df.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where($"rn" <=5).drop("rn")` only this particular val did a trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Scala Code for achieving the desired output

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
scala> df2.show
+---------------+-------------------+
|             id|           DateTime|
+---------------+-------------------+
|340054675199675|15-01-2018 19:43:23|
|340054675199675|15-01-2018 10:56:43|
|340028465709212|10-01-2018 02:47:11|
|340054675199675|09-01-2018 10:59:10|
|340028465709212|02-01-2018 03:25:35|
|340054675199675|28-12-2017 05:48:04|
|340054675199675|21-12-2017 15:47:51|
|340028465709212|18-12-2017 10:33:04|
|340028465709212|16-12-2017 19:55:40|
|340028465709212|16-12-2017 19:55:40|
|340028465709212|12-12-2017 07:04:51|
|340054675199675|06-12-2017 08:52:38|
+---------------+-------------------+


scala> df2.printSchema
root
   |-- id: string (nullable = true)
   |-- DateTime: string (nullable = true)
```

> Dataframe COLUMN(DateTime) is in string format, so need to convert into timestamp so that we can easily sort the data based on the requirement.

```
 var df3 = df2.withColumn("DateTime",to_timestamp($"DateTime","dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
 scala> df3.printSchema
 root
   |-- id: string (nullable = true)
   |-- DateTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

> Apply Window function for retrieving the desired output

```
 val w= Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("DateTime")
 val dfTop = df3.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).filter($"rn"<6).drop(col("rn"))

 scala> dfTop.show
 +---------------+-------------------+
 |             id|           DateTime|
 +---------------+-------------------+
 |340028465709212|2017-12-12 07:04:51|
 |340028465709212|2017-12-16 19:55:40|
 |340028465709212|2017-12-16 19:55:40|
 |340028465709212|2017-12-18 10:33:04|
 |340028465709212|2018-01-02 03:25:35|
 |340054675199675|2017-12-06 08:52:38|
 |340054675199675|2017-12-21 15:47:51|
 |340054675199675|2017-12-28 05:48:04|
 |340054675199675|2018-01-09 10:59:10|
 |340054675199675|2018-01-15 10:56:43|
 +---------------+-------------------+
```

Then you will get exactly what you want as Answer.HAppy HAdooooop